# on Submit add input to form than submit the updated form vanilla js

Tags: javascript

I have a form with `onsubmit='ConsolidateRTFEdits(event)'`

and the function is as follows:

```
function ConsolidateRTFEdits(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    const editor_fields = document.querySelectorAll( '.ckeditor-widget' );
    const form = event.target;
    editor_fields.forEach(field => {
        input = document.createElement("input");
        input.setAttribute('type', "hidden") 
        input.setAttribute('name', field.dataset.ck) 
        input.setAttribute('value', field.ckeditorInstance.getData()) 
        form.append(input)
    })
    form.submit()
```

I can successfully log the form with added input, as well as see it updated on the DOM, however form.submit() submits the form without the appended attribute.

What am I doing wrong?
**How to sumit the updated form?**
I have also tried to add an id and `document.getElementById()` the same form afterwards, but does not work either.

Comment: does `form.appendChild(input)` work?

Comment: I have a feeling, that at the time of onsubmit it is too late to change the form. Maybe try changing it sooner, onclick on a button maybe and then programmatically send the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already overriding the submit handler, my recommendation is to find a better way to achieve what you need. if it's not possible, I can suggest three approaches to get it fixed:

1. After manipulating your form, do the submission logic manually from JavaScript
2. Or, use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and [removeEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener), to add a custom handler and remove it before re-triggering the event

```js
const formElement = document.forms['myForm'];

formElement.addEventListener('submit', customHandler);

function customHandler(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  //....
  formElement.removeEventListener('submit', customHandler);
  formElement.submit();
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm" id="myForm">
  <input type="text">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

3. *from comments above*, change the button type to be `button` not `submit`, and add the needed logic to its `onclick` handler, then trigger submitting the form!

Comment: solution 2 requires hitting the submit button twice. Is there a fix for that?